# What is the meaning of the medium Effect size=0.25 in ANCOVA models

Tags: effect-size

I was wondering what is the meaning of medium effect size (Cohen's f) for ANCOVA analysis. I would appreciate if provide me some information by an example.

Comment: Do you have survey data or anything else ?  Pleaze elaborate your data and problem ?

Comment: @subhash c. davar, thanks for the comment, I want to calculate the sample size and I want to know what is the meaning of Cohen effect size and how I can interpret the medium effect size?

Comment: Unless and untill, a few details about what you are doing are mentioned, it is not possible for me to respond accurately. Please do indicate the problem you want a solution for.

Comment: Elaborate Ancova as well.